# How to clone element with new id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements on the page. Here is example of one element:

```
<div id="119" class="message">
<div class="messageAuthor">iggy</div>
<div class="messageBody messageMessage">hello</div>
<div class="messageDate messageCreate_date">12:13</div>
</div>
```

I get from server new items and items which were updated in JSON. Here is example of using JSON response:

```
$.each(ajaxResult.items, function(index) {
    for (var key in ajaxResult.items[index]) {
        if (ajaxResult.items[index].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if ($('.'+ajaxResult.controller + self.toUpperFirst(key)).length) {
                if ($('#'+ajaxResult.items[index].id).length) {
                    $('#'+ajaxResult.items[index].id).children('.'+ajaxResult.controller + self.toUpperFirst(key)).text(ajaxResult.items[index][key]);
                }
                else {
                    var prevIndex = parseInt(index) - 1;

                    $('#'+ajaxResult.items[prevIndex].id).after($('#'+ajaxResult.items[prevIndex].id).html());
                }

            }
        }
    }
});
```

I want to add new elements after existing elements. I don't know what the best way to do it. I need help.

Comment: What's your question here? There are several functions you can use to clone elements or create elements, such as clone() and append()

Comment: I want to clone existing element to create new alements from json response. But i need to increment id of newly created elements.

Comment: you can set the id attribute with `jquery_element.attr('id', id_new_element)`

Comment: Please edit in the pertinent details into the question, such as making it clear that your question is really about getting unique id's, and not about the actual cloning process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
jQuery(element).clone().attr('id',new_id).appendTo(parent_element);
```